# Crashes fragement when passing arguments to previous fragment

Tags: android

I have three fragments FragA, FragB, FragC. Am passing an argument through bundle "discount" from FragA to FragB. Then from FragB am sending two arguments "discount" and "address" to FragC. Till here all are working properly.

Then i have to go back to FragB from FragC. I used a button 'backButton' for this purpose. But when the button clicks, my app crashes due to NPE. I have send argument to FragB from FragC, but no arguments will get in FragB.

Am attaching the code i have used below..

***Fragement A***

```
    class FragA extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    {
        context = getActivity();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragfirst, container, false);

        nextButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                fr = new FragB();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("discount", discount);
                    fr.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***Fragement B***

```
    class FragB extends Fragment
{
    Context context;
    String discount = "";
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    {
        context = getActivity();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragsec, container, false);
        String addressid = "something";
        nextButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);

        Bundle b = getArguments();
        discount = b.getString("discount");

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                fr = new FragC();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("discount", discount);
                    bundle.putString("address", addressid);
                    fr.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***Fragement C***

```
   class FragC extends Fragment
{
    Context context;
    String discount = "",addressid="";
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    {
        context = getActivity();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragthird, container, false);
        backButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);

        Bundle b = getArguments();
        discount = b.getString("discount");

//backButton to go to Fragment B(FragB)
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                fr = new FragB();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("discount", discount);
                    fr.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

***LogCat***

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>            at com.abc.fragments.FragA.onCreateView(FragA.java:114)
>            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
>            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
>            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
>            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
>            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
>            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Please Suggest me a solution...

Comment: post `LogCat` of crash report

Comment: i have attached the logcat error report with my question

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be NullPointerException....
as you are extracting arguments in onCreateView but when you are going back getArguments must be giving you null a there is no argument passed from FragC to FragB... it better you put null check around bundle

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
if( b != null )
        discount = b.getString("discount");
```

when you press back button you are restoring your pervious fragment... but in you code you are going Frag A >Frag  B >Frag  C >Frag  B ....you are implementing it wrong way... just dont add Frag B to stack of fragment

Comment: the argument is getting null. I actually don't need it to be null. for that am passing arguments  from FragC to FragB